# How to check whether tasks in io_service are completed?

Tags: c++, boost, concurrency, boost-asio, asio

I have a question about `boost::io_service`.

I have a set of tasks that I can run concurrently. After running all of them, I need to run another set of tasks concurrently. However first set has to be completed before starting to run the second set. This means I need to make sure that all the jobs submitted to io_service is completed before starting to schedule to second set.

I can implement it by keeping some kind of counter and add a busy loop but it does not look very efficient. So, I wanted to checked whether someone has a better idea or not. Following is a dummy code that I was using to experiment.

Thank you in advance!

```cpp
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
 #include <boost/bind.hpp>
 #include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

 const size_t numTasks = 100000;

 void print_counter(const size_t id)
 {
   if (id + 1 == numTasks) {
     printf("sleeping for %ld\n", id);
     sleep(15);
   }
   printf("%ld\n", id);
 }

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
   using namespace std;
   using namespace boost;

   asio::io_service io_service;
   asio::io_service::work work(io_service);

   const size_t numWorker = 4;
   boost::thread_group workers;
   for(size_t i = 0; i < numWorker; ++i) {
     workers.create_thread(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
   }

   for(size_t i = 0; i < numTasks; ++i) {
     io_service.post(boost::bind(print_counter, i));
   }

   // TODO: wait until all the tasks are done above


   for(size_t i = 0; i < numTasks; ++i) {
     io_service.post(boost::bind(print_counter, i));
   }

   // TODO: wait until all the tasks are done above

   // ...

   // Finally stop the service
   io_service.stop();
   workers.join_all();
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I reset a deadline_timer to signal "events" in async code. Otherwise, use futures (but it's not straight as forward in Asio)

Comment: How Timer will help?

Answer (score 4):

Your main problem is that all sets of your tasks are processed by the same instance of `io_service`. Function `io_service::run` returns where there is no tasks to be processed. Destructor of `io_service::work` informs `io_service` object that `run` can return where there are no pending tasks in queue to be performed. You can post all tasks from first set, then destroyed work and wait until `io_service::run` returns, then create again `work` object, post tasks from the next set and delete work, and so on. To do it just write helper class which may look like something below:

```
class TasksWaiter 
{
public:
    TasksWaiter(int numOfThreads) 
    {
        work = std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(io_service);
        for(size_t i = 0; i < numOfThreads; ++i) {
            workers.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
        }
    }

    ~TasksWaiter() {
        work.reset();
        workers.join_all();
    }

    template<class F>
    void post(F f) {
        io_service.post(f);
    }

    boost::thread_group workers;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work;
};

int main()
{
    {
        TasksWaiter w1{4};
        for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; ++i)
            w1.post(boost::bind(print_counter,i));
        // work in w1 is destroyed, then io_service::run ends 
        // when there are no tasks to be performed
    }
    printf("wait here");
    {
        TasksWaiter w1{4};
        for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; ++i)
            w1.post(boost::bind(print_counter,i));
    }
}
```

a few remarks:

1. in constructor pool of threads are created
2. in destructor work is deleted, so `io_service::run` returns only if there are no pending tasks
3. functionality of destructor can be wrapped into a member function - e.g. `wait`, then you don't have to use `{}` scope to wait for your tasks.

Comment: I do not have access to my workstation to test it now but it seems this what i was looking for. i will try and let you know, thank you!

Comment: @rafix07, This is wrong, "Destructor of io_service::work informs io_service object that run can return where there are no pending tasks in queue to be performed" .

Comment: @Explorer_N Nice comment but it doesn't explain at all what is wrong in my answer ? . If I replaced *pending tasks* by *unfinished tasks* my answer matches to description of *work* class destructor, according to [reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__work/_work.html).

Comment: @rafix07, I didn't say your answer is wrong, what I meant to say is, a piece of your answer is not exactly correct. "Destructor of `io_service::work` " only informs `io_service` that a work has been finished, the rest of what (when no workers then stop) you said is taken care by `io_service`.

Answer (score -1):

From [the `io_service::run` documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/run/overload1.html):

> The `run()` function **blocks until all work has finished** and there are no more handlers to be dispatched, or until the `io_context` has been stopped.

Also, from [the `io_context::work` constructor documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__work/work/overload1.html):

> The constructor is used to inform the `io_context` that some work has begun. This ensures that the `io_context` object's `run()` function **will not exit while the work is underway**.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

In short, if the `run` function returns and [`stopped`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/stopped.html) returns false, then all work has been finished.

Comment: " if the run function returns and stopped returns false", 

`run` function return when `stopped` is true, when `stopped` is false, the run loop will continue to `run`

Comment: @Explorer_N Please read the quote from the documentation (or the linked documentation itself). That implies that `run` can return without the context being stopped.

Comment: Quote from document: "A normal exit from the run() function implies that the io_context object is stopped (the stopped() function returns true). Subsequent calls to run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() will return immediately unless there is a prior call to restart()."

Comment: " if the run function returns and stopped returns false, then all work has been finished" read your own quote again.